# Subset order 50 of $\{1,2,..,99\}$ has two numbers such that their sum is 99

Tags: contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

I ran into problem from "Putnam and Beyond" from section about Pigeonhole principle. I was thinking about that problem few hours but unfortunately i was not able to solve it. Also I have found the duplication of this topic but it did not help me since solutions are not quite detailed.

Given $50$ distinct positive integers strictly less than $100$, prove that some two of them sum to $99$.

**My efforts:** Let $S=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{50}\}\subset \{1,2,\dots, 99\}$ and $x_i+x_j=99$ **iff** $(x_i,x_j)\in \{(1,98),(2,97),\dots,(49,50)\}$. Here we have $49$ pairs of numbers such that their sum is $99$.

1) What here should be boxes and pigeons?

2) And how to use that all 50 distinct positive integers are strictly less than 100?

Comment: In your set, there can only be one number from each pair that sums up to 99. Meaning after choosing 49 numbers, you have to choose a number that pairs to overall sum $99$ with one already chosen. Therefore boxes are pairs and pigeons are chosen numbers I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your attempt gives a counter example
$$
1,2,3,4,\dots, 49, 99.
$$

But it does not mean that you did it wrong, since the main thoughts for this question is to pick pairs and create the "boxes". I'd rather believe  there is a typo on your book.

So here we require that all $50$ numbers are strictly less than $\mathbf{99}$, **instead of** $100$. Then you've almost got it. Here the $49$ pairs you've found are the "boxes", and the $50$ numbers are the "pigeons". Hence there must be a pair lies in the set of these $50$ numbers by the piegon-hole principle.

**UPDATE**

The pigeon-hole principle tells us that there are 2 numbers $x_j, x_k $ in the same "box". Since these 2 numbers are **distinct**, these two form a pair in the box. By the fact that the sum of the pair in each box is $99$ [as you constructed], we have $x_j + x_k = 99$

**UPDATE 2**

Now I explain it from a different point of view, which is mathematically equivalent to the question.

Suppose you were required to pick out $50$ numbers from $1$ through $98$. Then the pigeonhole principle tells you that you have to pick two number from the same box you've created, which means at least one box is empty now. Equivalently the pair originally lay in this box was picked out by you, and they sum up to $99$.

Comment: You said my attempt? What do you mean by "my attempt". I just picked pairs, nothing more

Comment: @RFZ But that is the main step to crack this problem, i.e. picking pairs.

Comment: So you think that my efforts are false, right? So what i should do in order to solve this problem correctly?

Comment: @RFZ No. I mean that YOU did it right, but the QUESTION is wrong, which is explained by the counter example. The conclusion holds for "less than 99" situation. "100" is a typo, I assume.

Comment: @RFZ Now see my edit. Sorry that I made the answer confusing

Comment: I thought very carefully about that problem, however, there is one moment that I can't understand. Please explain me that: Let's consider arbitrary subset $S$ with $50$ elements from the set $\{1,2,..,98\}$. Let's take $49$ pairs $(1,98), (2,97), \dots, (49,50)$ and we will consider them as "boxes". The pigeons are arbitrary subset $S$ with 50 element from $\{1,2,\dots,98\}$. By pigeonhole principle since $50>49$ then at least 2 numbers $x_i,x_j$ (pigeons) should be at the same "box". Why it follows that $x_i+x_j=99$? Could you explain me that please. I can't understand that properly.

Comment: @RFZ See my update

Comment: Why they form a pair in a box? That is my main question

Comment: see my update 2

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

We divide the positive integers into pairs like: $$\{1,98\}, \{2,97\}, \ldots \{49,50\}$$

These are our $49$ boxes, and as you can see, that if we pick any fifty integers (**pigeons**), by the pigeonhole principle, we have to pick two integers from the same pair, thus, two numbers sum to $99$.

P.S. It doesn’t make any sense to count 99 as well.

Comment: What if we take numbers $1,2,3,4,\dots,49,99$? Then we have counterexample

Comment: @RFZ Yes, it does not make any sense to pick 99 and then say sum of any two will be 99.